# My VPS has been shut down now again for the second time for TOS violations, and I really need some help.

Tags: email, apache, spam, joomla

My VPS has been shut down now again for the second time for TOS violations (email spam), and I really need some help. I have been battling with my server being attacked for over a year now. Most of my sites are running Joomla ranging from 1.5 installs (which cannot be upgraded because the customers have declined the upgrade, really its only 2 sites running 1.5) to 3.1 installs. I am not sure where the vulnerability is. i have gone through all of my scripts and enabled captcha, changed my admin passwords, changed my database passwords, and checked my extensions against joomla's vulnerable extension list. what else can i set up to prevent this from happening? THis is about my 5th attack in a year, and about my 5th time tightening the belt on everything just to have my efforts fail....grrrrr

Comment: Simply shut off sites that will not upgrade. Failure to follow a proper upgrade path which allows for everyone else to lose their services should not be tolerated.

Answer (score 2):

Don't host customers who decline to keep their software updated. **There is no other option** if you don't want your sites to be hacked.  It is impossible to secure vulnerable software.

Also, any site that has been hacked needs to be wiped out completely and reinstalled from scratch or a known-good backup. Again, no other option is safe.

Answer (score 0):

Identify the source of the compromise and drop the client if they won't fix their vulnerabilities (or charge them for their own dedicated VPS and tell them they are responsible for the compromises.)  The only way to stop being compromised is to fix the problems allowing you to be compromised.

Comment: I do not believe he fully knows where he is being compromised which could be part of the problem

Comment: @Ekaj - that may be the case, but in that case, without more details, we can't really help him with that either and it would likely be too localized anyway.